# Rust function that can return more than one type?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and there is a function in `actix-web` that intrigue me. To create a router in `actix`, we need to pass a function (`handle_get_insert` for example) that implements `actix_web::Responder`

```
// main.rs
cfg.service(
    web::resource("/items/get")
        .route(web::get().to(handle_get_item))
        .route(web::head().to(|| HttpResponse::MethodNotAllowed())),

// handle_get_item is a function that returns any type that implement use actix_web::Responder
// Here Responder means any type that it return must have #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)] 
pub async fn handle_get_item(....) -> impl Responder {
    match reply {
        Ok(item_doc) => {
            let result = GetReply {
                id: String::from(inf.id.to_string()),
                doc: Some(item_doc),
                ok: true,
            };
            // convert the result into json
            return web::Json(result);
        }
        Err(e) => {
            let result = ErrorReply {
                error: format!("{}", e),
                ok: false,
            };
            // error is occurred here: expected struct "GetReply", found struct "ErrorReply"
            return web::Json(result);
        }
    }
}
```

this `handle_get_item` can return two type of value (`GetReply` for data and `ErrorReply` if an error occurred). Both types have the same traits but with different fields in it.

To my surprise, Rust only recognize one of them as the return type, and throws an error on the `ErrorReply`:

```
error: mismatched types
label: expected struct "GetReply", found struct "ErrorReply"
```

which means that Rust only recognizes `GetReply` as the returned value and forces each exit point to implements the same `GetReply` type.

Does it possible to return two types ? or this is not supposed to be happen in `actix` ?

Comment: Functions returning `impl Trait` return one concrete type deduced from what is actually returned from the function. Read more: https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both types have the same traits but with different fields in it.

Yes but as Ivan C noted that's not what `impl Trait` does. `impl Trait` is essentially a placeholder for a normal type which implements the trait (it also makes the return type opaque which lets you e.g. return private types from pub functions).

> Does it possible to return two types ?

Technically no, a Rust function can only return values of one type, however there are usually ways around this. One is to return a *dynamically dispatched* object via `Box`. This is slightly less efficient, but if the trait is [object-safe](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0255-object-safety.html) (note: I've no idea if Responder is) then it lets you leverage [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) to kinda-sorta return different types from the same function.

An alternative is that the one trait is basically just an intermediate step and ends up converting to a single concrete type at the end. While you'd usually return something implementing the trait for convenience you can… take the final step yourself "by hand".

In Actix, I expect that's [`HttpResponse`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.HttpResponse.html), which you can either build "by hand" or using [`Responder::respond_to`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/trait.Responder.html#tymethod.respond_to).

Comment: Or return an enum? In this case `Result<impl Responder, impl Responder>` looks quite apt.

Comment: I finally use  `fn handle_get_item() -> Result<impl Responder, ItemError>` if. it was OK then `Ok(web::Json(...))` and if it was error then I just called `Err(e)`